# Where is Crashlytics API Key & Crashlytics Build Secret running fastlane init

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, fastlane

Running Fastlane `fastlane init` You get asked for:

Crashlytics API Key & Crashlytics Build Secret, but where can you find this information.

I can find the `google-services.json`, but I dont know if that will cover the information, if I somehow add it to Appfile or Fastfile?

Comment: Any solution did you have?

Comment: Nope, I went one to other problems - but I will get back on this in a few weeks. Let me know if you come any information.

Answer (score 1):

Those keys are in your google services file.

in google-services.json

```
   "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "AIzaSy********************"
        }
      ],
```

I guess firebase deprecated build secret:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution/android/distribute-fastlane

UPDATE:
When I try again I got this warning from fastlane

> This action (crashlytics) is deprecated Crashlytics Beta has been
> deprecated and replaced with Firebase App Distribution. Beta will
> continue working until May 4, 2020. Check out the "Firebase App
> Distribution docs"
> (https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane-plugin-firebase_app_distribution
> ) to get started.